How to use regex to extract a set of particular substrings?
I want to extract all possible substrings which have all the vowels from a string. For example in the code:
import re
text = "thisisabeautifulsequencofwords"
pattern = r"(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)[ \w]*?"
match = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)
print(match)

I want to get the following outputs:
['thisisabeautifulsequenco','thisisabeautifulsequencof','sisabeautifulsequenco'....]

How to do that?

The code below can help you with your problem using Regix re in Python.
import re

def get_substrings_with_all_vowels_regex(text):
    pattern = r'(?=(.{5,}))'  # Positive lookahead for substrings of length >=5
    matches = []

    # Iterate over all possible starting positions
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
        start = match.start()
        # Try all possible substrings starting from 'start' position
        for end in range(start + 5, len(text) + 1):
            substring = text[start:end]
            if all(vowel in substring for vowel in 'aeiou'):
                matches.append(substring)
         return matches

text = "thisisabeautifulsequencofwords"
result = get_substrings_with_all_vowels_regex(text)
print(result)


You want to extend a final result list of strings with the matches list at every outer for loop iteration. Also indentation is missing..

Corrected Identation.
Can you share the code of the matches string comparison with the result? I don't get it.

Init the new list matches_final=[] then instead of return matches do matches_final.append(matches) then your function should return the newly created list

I would approach that task without using regular expressions, namely
text = "thisisabeautifulsequencofwords"
vowels = set("aeiou")
substrings = []
for start in range(len(text)+1):
   for end in range(start+1,len(text)+1):
       sub = text[start:end]
       if vowels.issubset(sub):
           substrings.append(sub)
print(*substrings, sep="\n")

gives output
thisisabeautifulsequenco
thisisabeautifulsequencof
thisisabeautifulsequencofw
thisisabeautifulsequencofwo
thisisabeautifulsequencofwor
thisisabeautifulsequencofword
thisisabeautifulsequencofwords
hisisabeautifulsequenco
hisisabeautifulsequencof
hisisabeautifulsequencofw
hisisabeautifulsequencofwo
hisisabeautifulsequencofwor
hisisabeautifulsequencofword
hisisabeautifulsequencofwords
isisabeautifulsequenco
isisabeautifulsequencof
isisabeautifulsequencofw
isisabeautifulsequencofwo
isisabeautifulsequencofwor
isisabeautifulsequencofword
isisabeautifulsequencofwords
sisabeautifulsequenco
sisabeautifulsequencof
sisabeautifulsequencofw
sisabeautifulsequencofwo
sisabeautifulsequencofwor
sisabeautifulsequencofword
sisabeautifulsequencofwords
isabeautifulsequenco
isabeautifulsequencof
isabeautifulsequencofw
isabeautifulsequencofwo
isabeautifulsequencofwor
isabeautifulsequencofword
isabeautifulsequencofwords
sabeautifulsequenco
sabeautifulsequencof
sabeautifulsequencofw
sabeautifulsequencofwo
sabeautifulsequencofwor
sabeautifulsequencofword
sabeautifulsequencofwords
abeautifulsequenco
abeautifulsequencof
abeautifulsequencofw
abeautifulsequencofwo
abeautifulsequencofwor
abeautifulsequencofword
abeautifulsequencofwords
beautifulsequenco
beautifulsequencof
beautifulsequencofw
beautifulsequencofwo
beautifulsequencofwor
beautifulsequencofword
beautifulsequencofwords
eautifulsequenco
eautifulsequencof
eautifulsequencofw
eautifulsequencofwo
eautifulsequencofwor
eautifulsequencofword
eautifulsequencofwords
autifulsequenco
autifulsequencof
autifulsequencofw
autifulsequencofwo
autifulsequencofwor
autifulsequencofword
autifulsequencofwords

Explanation: I use nested for-loop to get starts and ends of every non-zero-length substring, then I check if vowels are subset of characters in said substring and if so I append them to substrings list.

While this does work, the problem is it solves the problem in order of n^2.  I slightly modified the code and added a break sentence to skip when it is already known that there aren't all the vowels in the substring to reduce the number of iterations, but is there any way I can further modify to increase time efficiency?
changes i made:
for end in range(len(text),start+4,-1):        sub = text[start:end]       if vowels.issubset(sub):          substrings.append(sub)       else: break 
